# When we link a question with another and how can I do that?

Tags: discussion

I have posted the question [How can I safely convey at interview about my failure in previous project with less negative impact?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/how-can-i-safely-convey-at-interview-about-my-failure-in-previous-project-with-l) and one of the high rep user linked this to [Is it worth to tell a “Samaritan” (company mentor) about my story of particular failure?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/is-it-worth-to-tell-a-samaritan-company-mentor-about-my-story-of-particular?lq=1)

Now my questions are
(1) why this question is linked with another?
(2) What norms that we have to follow while linking the question?
(3) When it is appropriate to link one question with another?
(4) How can I link with one question with another?

**Research that I have done:**
I have searched in workplace meta for this question. Unfortunately I didn't get any results which answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

You searched the wrong meta for an answer. This topic is extensively covered at MSO, there is even a dedicated **[meta-tag:linked-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-questions)** there, with 40+ questions addressing various aspects of this functionality.

In particular, respective [tag wiki at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/linked-questions/info) currently state:

> The "Linked Questions" sidebar is a user-generated list of related questions shown when viewing a question. **Its content comes from questions that users have linked in the question, their answers, or in comments.**

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you were the person who linked in the other question question, and gnat simply cleaned it up so that the linked text was more meaningful, letting readers know more about where the link might lead.

You also linked it for a very good reason. The question was similar to yours, but it didn't answer your question. Adding in the information about why it didn't answer your question is textbook perfect! :)  It helps keep your question from getting closed as a duplicate, and it helps other answerers know what information you *don't* need.

To link a question to another, do exactly what you did initially, but instead of using the text "this", try to make the link a sentence or meaningful phrase.

For example, if I were to suggest you read about [how to answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) a question on The Workplace, I'd link the guide in like I just did, not just say "read [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)".

To create a link, in case it's not clear, use the following markup:

```
[This link goes to Google](http://google.com)
```

Comment: There's a variety of ways to do links, but that way is by far easiest imo